# phpMyadmin database export resulting error

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

i want export database from phpMyadmin but i have this error, i use php 8.2.11

[image]

when exporting it shows an error as above, Please help me

Comment: Check the webserver error log to see what caused the 500 error. The 500 code is a very general error that can be caused by MANY situations.